# move existing magento 2.3 website to RKE

Tags: magento2.3, docker

I am new to Magento, currently, I make a Magento website using 2.3.1 and one droplets. and everything works very well. i wanna try to move it to a K8s. how can i choose a Magento docker image to start work with it? hope someone gives me a good way to set it up.

plan to use Rancher 2 with ubuntu 18.04 as host OS

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2

use this as a base image of magento docker.